# Magento - How to get which store a country is allowed in

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I would like to be able to input a country and have it return the store where that country is allowed.

**Example:** *I'm using the the store code in a link to go to the right instance of my site (for example, frfr if I have a french address or wwuk if I have a american address)*

Here is what I have so far:

```
$allowed = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/country/allow');
$countriesAllowed = explode(',', $allowed);
$allowedstoreCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode($countriesAllowed);
```

It only returns the current store instead of the store where the country is allowed.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? Are you just trying to figure out if a country is allowed for a certain store? If so you're missing a country as input to see if it's valid.

Comment: Ok there is a miss in the Title. the good title is : How to GET the Store Code From authorized countries. For me it is 'frfr' or 'euuk' or 'wwuk' which is store in the core_store table.

Comment: I already figure out if a country is allowed for a certain store. I'm using the the store code in a link to go to the right instance of my site (for example frfr, if I have a french address, wwuk if I have a american address)